# OutputResponse gives the wrong results

Tags: control-systems

I have noticed that OutputResponse seems to give the wrong result in certain circumstances. I've created a toy example to compare the results obtained with Mathematica (which seems wrong) with the ones obtained with Matlab (which seems correct).

This is the code for the toy example:

```
R1 = 56*^3;
C1 = 680*^-12;
RCfilter = TransferFunctionModel[1/(1 + s R1 C1), s];
freq = 200/3;
inputSignal[t_] := TriangleWave[t *freq];
T1 = .02;
output = OutputResponse[RCfilter, inputSignal[t], {t, 0, T1}];
output2 = 
  OutputResponse[SystemsModelSeriesConnect[RCfilter, RCfilter], 
   inputSignal[t], {t, 0, T1}];
output3 = 
  OutputResponse[
   SystemsModelSeriesConnect[RCfilter, 
    SystemsModelSeriesConnect[RCfilter, RCfilter]], 
   inputSignal[t], {t, 0, T1}];
Plot[{inputSignal[t], output, output2, output3}, {t, 0, T1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

And this is the corresponding output:

[image]

`output` and `output2` look correct, but `output3`, orange in the picture, seems not.

This is the same example in Matlab:

```
s=tf('s');

R1=56e3;
C1=680e-12;
Hrc = 1/(1+s*R1*C1);

H = series(series(Hrc, Hrc), Hrc);

T = 1e-6;
tEnd = 0.02;
F = 200/3;
t = 0:T:tEnd;
u = sawtooth(t*2*pi*F + pi/2, 0.5);

figure;
plot(t,u);

figure;
lsim(H,u,t)
```

And this is the output (the blue line corresponds to `output3` in the Mathematica code):

[image]

I'm using Mathematica 11.0.1 and Matlab R2014b. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If *output3* is changed to

```
output3 = 
  OutputResponse[
   StateSpaceModel[
    SystemsModelSeriesConnect[RCfilter, 
     SystemsModelSeriesConnect[RCfilter, RCfilter]], 
    StateSpaceRealization -> "ObservableCompanion"], 
   inputSignal[t], {t, 0, T1}];
```

then it appears that the desired result is obtained.

[image]

There seems to be an incompatibility in the results with the default controllable companion form. Probably a bug, that needs to be investigated.

Comment: I filed a bug report with Wolfram. Thanks.